# Is there a limit of series connected LEDs when driving them with AC?

Tags: ac, led-strip

I want to drive as many as possible LEDs with AC grid voltage.

Assuming that there are \$n\$ LEDs connected in series, the voltage drop on the will be \$2.2nV\$. Then the voltage on the capacitor will be \$220V-2.2nV\$.

The capacitive reactance must be

$$ X_c = \dfrac{1}{2\pi(50Hz)C} = \dfrac{220V - 2.2nV}{100mA}. $$

The value of the capacitance follows as

$$ C = \dfrac{100mA}{(220V - 2.2nV)(2\pi (50Hz))}. $$

If everything is correct up to this point, I want to ask my question.

What limits the value of \$n\$? Of course, \$n\$ cannot be higher than the value which would make the forward voltage drop on the LED group higher than the peak value of the AC sinusoidal signal. But, is there any other physical limit below it? Is there anything that would make the circuit performance drop down, or break down something if I choose \$n\$ incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: what about the voltage drop of the diodes?

Comment: @TJ: Neglected. Adding the effect of bridge rectifier voltage drop doesn't add anything to the point of the question.

Comment: I read through most of your question thinking you had found LEDs with a 2.2 nanoVolt forward voltage drop! I was disappointed to realize that's not what you meant ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AC grid voltage may be 220VRMS but it's the peak voltage that dictates the peak current through the LEDs and the peak voltage of 220V AC is \$\sqrt2\$ higher at 311 volts.

The next issue with the formula is that when N is large, forward conduction won't happen until the instantaneous AC voltage rises above N*2.2 volts. This means that the peak of the LED current may indeed rise to 100mA but for a shorter period of time compared to when N is small.

This will mean that as N increases (and C increases in order to push a peak current of 100mA into the string of LEDs), the duration in time that the current is flowing gets smaller and smaller and the LEDs get dimmer and dimmer.

If not saying this method isn't OK but I am saying the formula doesn't really prove useful for anything at the moment.